# Reorder matrix columns by variable groupings

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I'm writing a rotation matrix function that I want to work with vector inputs.  The goal is to return a cell array of rotation matrices for each of the angles in the vector "angle". However, the cosine and sine functions return row arrays when given a vector input, so the final matrix going into the mat2cell call needs to have its columns rearranged depending on the size of "angle", ie to have the correct 3 columns per input angle.  Here is an example of the input, function call, function, and result.

```
angle = [0 90];
RotZ(angle);
```

Call to RotZ

```
function [ rot ] = RotZ(angle)
%RotX Rotation matrix about Z axis
%   Generates a rotation matrix about Z axis for the  given angle in
%   degrees
angle = deg2rad(angle);

rot =   [cos(angle)           -sin(angle)         zeros(size(angle));...
         sin(angle)           cos(angle)          zeros(size(angle));...
         zeros(size(angle))   zeros(size(angle))  ones(size(angle))];
break
  if size(angle,2)>1
    rot = mat2cell(rot,3,3*ones(size(rot,2)/3,1));
  end
end
```

Returns matrix rot: (before mat2cell call)

```
rot =

    1.0000    0.0000         0   -1.0000         0         0
         0    1.0000    1.0000    0.0000         0         0
         0         0         0         0    1.0000    1.0000
```

I need a generalized way to group every 1+nth column where n is the number of elements in "angle".  The correct matrix for a two element vector "angle" should have columns ordered [1 3 5] and [2 4 6].  For a two angle input this is trivial, but I don't know how to generalize for larger size vectors of "angle" ie angle = [0 45 90 etc...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to group or determine which indices to select from each column to build a rotation matrix per angle, try using [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and iterate through each value in `angle`. With this, you can specify the `uni=0` flag to output a cell array.  I would rather do it this way because `mat2cell` essentially uses a `for` loop under the hood.  If you're going to do that, you might as well use `arrayfun` and the loop is more sensible to use.

Try doing something like this:

```
function [ rot ] = RotZ(angle)
%RotX Rotation matrix about Z axis
%   Generates a rotation matrix about Z axis for the  given angle in
%   degrees
angle = deg2rad(angle);

f = @(x)[cos(x) -sin(x) 0;...
         sin(x) cos(x) 0;...
         0 0 1];

rot = arrayfun(f, angle, 'uni', 0);

end
```

`rot` will contain a cell array of 3 x 3 rotation matrices for each angle stored in `angle`.  BTW, [`angle`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/angle.html) is an actual function in MATLAB so calling a variable in that way would unintentionally shadow over the command itself, so if you wanted to use it later, you wouldn't be able to.

---

Here's an example run given a bunch of angles:

```
ang = [0 30 60 90 120];
rot = RotZ(ang);
```

We get:

```
>> celldisp(rot)

rot{1} =

     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1



rot{2} =

    0.8660   -0.5000         0
    0.5000    0.8660         0
         0         0    1.0000



rot{3} =

    0.5000   -0.8660         0
    0.8660    0.5000         0
         0         0    1.0000



rot{4} =

    0.0000   -1.0000         0
    1.0000    0.0000         0
         0         0    1.0000



rot{5} =

   -0.5000   -0.8660         0
    0.8660   -0.5000         0
         0         0    1.0000
```

---

However, if you prefer to do it your way, we can generate a matrix of indices where each column corresponds to the order of which columns you would need to sample from the matrix.  You can easily achieve that by specifying a vector from `1` up to `3M` where `M` is the total number of elements in `angle`.  After, use [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html).  For example, given that we have two matrices, you would do this:

```
>> M = 2;
>> ind = reshape(1:3*M, M, []).'

ind =

     1    2   
     3    4 
     5    6
```

Similarly when `M = 3`:

```
>> M = 3;
>> ind = reshape(1:3*M, M, []).'

ind =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9
```

As you can see, for each column there are three values as we need three columns to build a rotation matrix and each value is `M` away from each other.  These values are used to construct the rotation matrices to be sampled from the larger matrix `rot`.  Also, the exact ordering you need per matrix is maintained. Next, we can perform a **reordering** of the matrix `rot` so that each consecutive chunk of three columns corresponds to a particular rotation matrix.  You can then invoke `mat2cell` on this reordered matrix:

```
rot = rot(:, ind(:));
rot = mat2cell(rot, 3, 3*ones(M,1));
```

The first line is a bit tricky, but nothing we can't handle.  We are accessing all of the rows of `rot` but we want to select out which columns we want out of `rot` and we want to place them in a particular order.  By doing `ind(:)`, we are **unrolling** the matrix `ind` into a vector where the columns of `ind` are stacked on top of the each other from the left column to the right column until we get a single vector out of this.  Once we do that, each triplet of distinct values in `ind` corresponds to the right columns of `rot` we would need to sample from to create our reordered matrix.  The result would be your large `rot` matrix, but consecutive triples of distinct columns yields a particular rotation matrix that you desire for each value of `angle`.  The last call is pretty straight forward.  Simply use `mat2cell` and split up the matrix into chunks of three and place each chunk into a cell array.

By running this, you'll also get what we did above.  To complete the picture, here's what your function would be:

```
function [ rot ] = RotZ(angle)
%RotX Rotation matrix about Z axis
%   Generates a rotation matrix about Z axis for the  given angle in
%   degrees
angle = deg2rad(angle);

rot =   [cos(angle)           -sin(angle)         zeros(size(angle));...
         sin(angle)           cos(angle)          zeros(size(angle));...
         zeros(size(angle))   zeros(size(angle))  ones(size(angle))];

M = numel(angle);
ind = reshape(1:3*M, M, []).';
rot = rot(:, ind(:));
rot = mat2cell(rot, 3, 3*ones(M,1));

end
```

Comment: Thank you so much rayryeng!  This is a much cleaner simpler solution.  Thank you also for taking the time to resolve the problem using my original approach, that will come in handy in the future.

Comment: No problem at all :) interesting problem this was. Good luck!